# Shortcut key in Ubuntu for accessing the Panel

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-panel

What is the shortcut key in Ubuntu for accessing the Panel? (The one with "Applications", "Places", etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: @OP: If you want to map it to "Windows" key, exec this in console: `gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/show_desktop --type string "Super_L"`.

Comment: Dang, I've been looking for this shortcut for ages, and I've already been using ALT+F2 for ages, I should've figured it out.